# Error when trying to accept a directory path as a command line argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to accept a directory path as a command line argument in order to check recently changed files - not too sure if I'm doing it correctly:

```
script=$scriptpath
find . "$scriptpath" / -user $USER -mtime -5
```

Comment: Try getting the argument inside single quotes.

Comment: Hi rahul - thanks for the comment- weird thing though, it lists all files changed. I'm looking to just check the ones that are in my specified directory that haven't been recently changed.

Comment: Remove the . and / and try..It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for a file name whose name is stored in scriptpath you need to use the `-name` option to find.

```
find / -name "$scriptpath" -user $USER -mtime -5
```

if you want to search the whole disk and

```
find . -name "$scriptpath" -user $USER -mtime -5
```

if you want to search from the current directory down.

This will give you the file if changed in the last 6 days (use `-time +5` if they need to be older than that).

Comment: I'm now getting a lot of permission denied errors - is that because I don't have authorisation to access them?

Comment: @user103001 if you are using `/` as the first parameter, that is very likely, a normal user cannot access the system files and subdirectories.

Comment: Great, that's now sorted - there's just one more thing - I'm trying to use the -prune in order to just display the contents of the directory - don't want a whole long list for where it's located. Is this right:

find / -name "$scriptpath" -prune -user $USER -mtime -5

Comment: @user103001 no `-prune` is used to cut of searching through part of the directory tree. Try piping into `| xargs dirname` if you just want to see the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `/` or other paths you don't need. Your command will search for what is in current directory `.`, `$scriptpath` and `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `.` after `find`, as that means it first searches your current directory and then whatever is in `$scriptpath`.